# Determining the Begin and End of Each Cycle in Quasi-Sinusoidal Timeseries Using Python

Tags: python, time-series, signal-processing, bioinformatics, data-preprocessing

I'm working on a project where I have quasi-sinusoidal bio-signal data collected from a sensor that's attached to an athlete's arm. I have to determine where each rep of the exercise the athlete performs starts and where it ends. For example, given the signal in the figure below, the output should be something like

```
Ex1: Timestamp1 - Timestamp2
Ex2: Timestamp2 - Timestamp3
...
```

I should leave out the rest periods, which are marked in red. Is there any Python library that offers such a method? If not, are there any published methods that I can look up and implement myself?

I have thought about utilizing the fact that each rep usually starts or ends when the signal crosses zero. However, crossings happen often during the rest period, and they might occur more than once during the exercise. (See the crossing next to the Timestamp2 crossing). So, I'm not sure if this fact could be utilized or not.

If you have a suggestion or a method in mind, I would be grateful if you could also mention whether this method is suitable for signals from multiple sensors, i.e., whether it could determine where the beginning and the end of each exercise is based on signals collected from multiple sensors attached to the athlete, not just the arm one.[image: Example of a biosignal timeseries]

Comment: If you base it on zero-upcrossings alone then it will be heavily influenced by the noise, though a low-pass filter could eradicate some of that. I would detect a rep with an upcrossing at a reasonably high positive trigger point. The start point could then be retrospectively put at the last zero upcrossing before that. The end point would be at the start of a period where it stays near zero for a significant time.

Comment: Alternatively, you could mark the periods where the signal remains in a set vicinity of zero for a set minimum time. The reps will be what remains.

Comment: Is the period for these readings always the same? Basically, do you have to predict both start and end or is end known once start is estimated properly?

Comment: @lastchance thanks a lot for your response! your idea sounds great. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @ATpoint unfortunately the period of the readings isn't fixed. Athletes might do some reps at a slower pace. So, I can't rely on it to predict the start and end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is such:

1. (optional) clear noise with some low-pass filtering.
2. find all peaks (top and bottom), you can use `scipy.signal.find_peaks` or some self-written code
3. group peaks into "single period pairs"
4. iterating from the top peak to the left, find first timestamp for which value gets close enough to 0, thats your excercise beginning
5. same to the right of the bottom peak - thats your end of the exercise

Comment: it's a similar idea to that of @lastchane, but you suggested looking for the peaks instead. I haven't used ```scipy.signal.find_peaks``` before, so I'll give it a try. Thanks for your reply.